# how to submit the values of one form to other form on submit

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, api, handlebars.js

Handlebar templete is used as views and nodejs is used in backend. i want to save detail in backend on submit of second form.

{{> alertmessage}}     
                            Website Name*
                            
                                
                                    
                                
                            
                        
                        
                            
                                Check Availability

```
                </form>

<form class="form-horizontal" action="/institute/create" method="POST">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="fullname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Institute Name*</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <div class="form-line">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="institute_name" name="institute_name"
                                        placeholder="institute_name" value="{{institute.institute_name}}" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
                                
div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
                                    <a class="btn btn-warning" href="/adminusers">Go to adminusers</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

 
instituteRouter.post('/checkSubdomainAvailability', async (req, res) => {
    let { success, error, validationError } = req.session;

    institute_subdomain = req.body.institute_subdomain;

    const response = await institute.findOne({ institute_subdomain: institute_subdomain }).exec();

    if (response === null) {
        console.log('response.institute_subdomain');
        req.session.success = 'Subdomain is available.'
        req.session.error = null;
        return res.redirect("/institute/create");
    }

    else {
        req.session.error = 'Subdomain is taken. Please try again.'
        req.session.success = null;
        return res.redirect("back");
    }
})
```

instituteRouter.post('/create', async (req, res) => {
let { success, error, validationError } = req.session;

```
check('owner', 'Please select owner.').notEmpty();

 let institute_subdomain = req.body.institute_subdomain;
let { institute_name } = req.body;
let pageToCreate = {
    institute_name, institute_subdomain
};
let createdPage = await institute.create(pageToCreate);
if (createdPage) {
    req.session.success = 'Institute created successfully.'
    return res.redirect('/institute');
}
else {
    req.session.error = 'Error occurred in creating a new page';
    return res.redirect('/institute');
}
```

})